# How can I find the last digit of $17^{68}$ and the last both digits of $14^{200}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have to compute the last digit of $17^{68}$ and the last both digits of $14^{200}$.

For the first exercise, I get

$$17^4=...1 \Rightarrow  17^{68}=(17^4)^{17} = (...1)^{17}=\ .... 1.$$

For the last exercise, I don't know how I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$100=4\times25$ and $gcd(4,25)=1$

$14^{200}\equiv2^{200}\times7^{200}\equiv0$ mod $4$ (since $4=2^2$)

$14^{200}\equiv(-11)^{200}\equiv11^{200}\equiv121^{100}\equiv(-4)^{100}\equiv4^{100}\equiv(-1)^{20}\equiv1$ mod $25$

(since $4^5=1024\equiv-1$ mod $25$)

So we have, for some integer $k$ :

$14^{200}=1+25k\equiv k+1\equiv0$ mod $4$

Therefore, for some integer $k'$ such that $k=-1+4k'$:

$14^{200}=1+25k=1+25\times(4k'-1)=-24+100k'\equiv 76$ mod $100$

Edit : your answer is okay for the first exercise, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For the first use modulo 10. For the second use modulo $100$.

Modulo $10$ means the remainder after a division with 10.

E.g. $$17 \equiv 7 \pmod {10}, 17^2\equiv49\pmod {10}=-1 \pmod {10}$$ and$$ 17^{68}=(-1)^{34}\pmod {10}\equiv1\pmod {10}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the second one:

$$14^2 = 196 = -4 \text{ mod } 100$$

Then successive powers of $-4$ mod $100$ are $-4, 16, -64, 56, -24, 96$.  (Aha!)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  & {{17}^{\varphi (10)}}={{17}^{4}}\overset{10}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,1\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,{{7}^{68}}\overset{10}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,1 \\ 
 & {{2}^{22}}\overset{100}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,4\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,\,{{2}^{198}}\overset{100}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,{{4}^{9}}\overset{100}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,44\,\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,\,{{2}^{200}}\overset{100}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,76 \\ 
 & {{14}^{2}}\overset{100}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,4\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,\,{{14}^{200}}\overset{100}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,{{2}^{200}}\overset{100}{\mathop{\equiv }}\,76 \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: Can check your work against [popular calculator software](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=14^200+mod+100) to avoid mistakes.

Comment: it was edited.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should start learning a bit of modular arithmetic to solve this kind of problems. To calculate the n last numbers of a p number we just calculate the:  $$ p \equiv {x}\ mod\ 10^n $$

In this case we got:

$$ 17^{68} \equiv 7^{68} \equiv (7^2)^{34} \equiv (-1)^{34} \equiv 1\ mod\ 10$$

The other case:

$$14^{200} \equiv (14^2)^{100} \equiv (-4)^{100} \equiv (-24)^{20} \equiv 76^5 \equiv 76\ mod\ 100$$